# Linear model of geom_histogram data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with dataset in which I have continuous variable x and categorical variables y and z. Something like this:

```
set.seed(222)
df = data.frame(x = c(0, c(1:99) + rnorm(99, mean = 0, sd = 0.5), 100),
           y = rep(50, times = 101)-(seq(0, 50, by = 0.5))+rnorm(101, mean = 30, sd = 20),
           z = rnorm(101, mean = 50, sd= 10))

df$positive.y = sapply(df$y,
                         function(x){
                           if (x >= 50){"Yes"} else {"No"}
                         })

df$positive.z = sapply(df$z,
                       function(x){
                         if (x >= 50){"Yes"} else {"No"}
                       })
```

Then using this dataset I can create histograms to see either there is correlation between variables *x* and *positive.y(z)*. With 10 bins it is clear that x correlates with positive.y, but not with positive.z:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, fill = positive.y))+
  geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 10)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, fill = positive.z))+
  geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 10)
```

Now from this I want two things:

1. Extract the actual data points to supply them to corr.test() function or something like that.
2. Add geom_smooth(method = "lm") to plot I have.

I tried to add "bin" column to the df, like this:

```
df$bin = sapply(df$x,
                function(x){
                  if (x <= 10){1}
                  else if (x > 10 & <= 20) {20}
                  else if .......
                })
```

Then using tapply() count number of "Yes" and "No" for each df$bin, and convert it to the %.
But in this case each time I change number of bins at histogram, I have to re-write and re-run this part of code which is tedious and consumes a lot of computer time if dataset is large.

Is there a more straightforward way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Use the `hist` function? I would not add an `lm` line. Logistic regression would appear to be a much better and appropriate model. You wouldn't need any binning for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a good justification for adding an `lm` line. Logistic regression is the appropriate model and doesn't require binning:

```
df$positive.y <- factor(df$positive.y)
mod <- glm(positive.y ~ x, data = df, family = "binomial")
summary(mod)
anova(mod)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, fill = positive.y))+
  geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 10) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = x), 
                                    type = "response"), 
    size = 2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

If you need an R² value (why?), there are different pseudo-R² [available](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8511/11849) for GLMs, e.g.,

```
library(fmsb)
NagelkerkeR2(mod) 
#$N
#[1] 101
#
#$R2
#[1] 0.4074274
```